# WSO2 API-Manager with Postgres database is not working properly

Tags: postgresql, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have shifted the default h2 database to Postgresql for WSO2 API Manager by following this documentation: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-postgresql/

Creating a new API on throws:

> "Something went wrong while getting the Revisions!"

On server found this error

> ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Failed to get API Revision deployment mapping details for api uuid: a96f7266-c340-49b6-bbe1-cb252b49860e
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: UNION types integer and boolean cannot be matched

Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks...

Comment: Well, the query is broken.

Comment: A possible reason could be that the PostgreSQL version you are using might not be supporting the relevant WSO2 APIM's DB queries. Please check whether the DB version you are using is supported by the APIM version you are using. You can check the following document for compatibility. The given document is for APIM-4.0.0, and if you are using another version, use the correct document.
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/reference/product-compatibility/